# How to type this advanced function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This is the tricky function :

```
function getPropertyName(obj, expression) {
    var res = {};
    Object.keys(obj).map(k => { res[k] = () => k; });
    return expression(res)();
}
```

And my unsuccessful attempt to type it :

```
  getPropertyName<T>(obj: T, expression: (o: T) => any): string {
    let res = {};
    Object.keys(obj).map(k => { res[k] = () => k; });
    return expression(res as T)();
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain in more details why it is "unsuccessful"? I mean what exact errors do you encounter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you no errors, however, your intention is not completely clear to me:

```
getPropertyName<T>(obj: T, expression: (o: T) => any): string {
    const res: { [key: string]: any } = {};
    Object.keys(obj).map((k) => { res[k] = () => k; });
    return expression(res as T)();
}
```